# Are UUID and Device token same?

Tags: ios9

I am new to iOS. Can anyone tell whether UUID and device token are same or not? Need to get clear idea about that. I think both are different. Can someone explain in what way they differ?

Answer (score 3):

UUID: A universally unique value that can be used to identify types, interfaces, and other items.[Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/uuid)
Apple is apparently starting to remove access to the UDID (Unique Device IDentifier) in iOS5. In any event, the best you can now do for identification purposes is to use a UUID (Universally Unique IDentifier). This has to be on a per-app basis. That is, there is no way to identify the device any longer, but you can identify an app on a device.As long as the user doesn’t completely delete the app, then this identifier will persist between app launches, and at least let you identify the same user using a particular app on a device. Unfortunately, if the user completely deletes and then reinstalls the app then the ID will change, but this is the best anyone can do going forward.

```
NSString* Identifier = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString]; // IOS 6+
NSLog(@"output is : %@", Identifier);
```

Swift:

```
let Identifier = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString

NSLog("output is : %@", Identifier! as String)
```

Device Token: Given By APNS server for Push notification purpose. it changes every app installation. also different for Sandbox and Production mode.

Comment: I tried this one..When i delete the app , device token differs from the previous one but UUID remains the same

Comment: @SuganyaMarlin. UUIDy remains the same while the app (or another app from the same vendor) is installed on the iOS device. The value changes when the user deletes all of that vendor’s apps from the device and subsequently reinstalls one or more of them. but they are different from Device token.there is no way to keep that UUID unique after app delete. we have to handle those cases.